# Getting maxima source block to return and display latex equations

Tags: org-babel, preview-latex, maxima

I'd like my maxima source blocks to return either valid latex that I can display in the org-buffer, or an image of the results (a la imaxima). Ideally, the pure latex solution would be best.

Here is an example which I'd like to work.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC maxima :results output raw
C: matrix([1, -1], [1, 1]);
V: matrix([\sigma[11], \sigma[12]], [\sigma[12], \sigma[22]]);
tex(C . V . transpose(C));
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
$$\pmatrix{\sigma_{22}-2\,\sigma_{12}+\sigma_{11}&\sigma_{11}-\sigma
 _{22}\cr \sigma_{11}-\sigma_{22}&\sigma_{22}+2\,\sigma_{12}+\sigma_{
 11}\cr }$$
```

The result doesn't render in my buffer.

Comment: A related issue I found was that after trying to render it a bunch of times, I can no longer toggle the display of latex fragments until after restarting emacs. I get the error: `Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil` coming from `org-remove-if`.

Comment: I have some examples here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wvxvw/uni-infinitesimal-calculus/HEAD/assignment-14.org and I too remember having troubles doing this. In the worst case you can feed the output of `tex()` to another Org block to format it the way you like.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [babel's recommendation](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-maxima.html) do you have this exports header someplace in the document?

```
#+header: :exports none
```

However for graphical rendering to file/displaying that file in-place, the manual recommends

```
#+header: :exports results
#+header: :results graphics
```

The other thing to check is the scale variable > 1 under `org-format-latex-options`. Yet I still get `number-or-marker-p` error every now and then.

Comment: My scale is 1.7 in `org-format-latex-options` because I have trouble reading the 1.0 setting. Changing that back to 1 let me render latex images again. More interestingly, once they rendered correctly, I set it back to 1.7 and it still worked.

Comment: I tried using :exports none, but that had no effect. I was, however, able to correctly display basic equations as latex; just not matrices.

Comment: Nevermind, the `number-or-marker-p` error came back.