# typesetting matrix output from maxima using org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, tex, maxima

How can I make org-mode typeset matrices output from maxima?

For example, the following code produces tex output that display

```
#+BEGIN_SRC maxima :results raw
m: matrix([1, 2], [3, 4]);
tex(m);
#+END_SRC
```

It produces the result:

```
#+RESULTS:
$$\pmatrix{1&2\cr 3&4\cr }$$
```

This does not display anything. Is there an easy way to make this code valid so that it will display?

Apparently I had mostly the same question 2 years ago (but with a more complicated example). Unfortunately, I didn't get a reproducible answer at the time:

[Getting maxima source block to return and display latex equations](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16711/getting-maxima-source-block-to-return-and-display-latex-equations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following comment about loading the maxima package `mactex-utilities` on http://maxima-discuss.narkive.com/fenby68e/export-tex-format

> Post by Paul RIVIER
>
> > I take this opportunity to ask you if there is a
> >     work in progress to include a latex export as well.
> >     I don't know of anybody that is working on this.
> >     To generate LaTeX output for fractions and matrices,
> >     load 'mactex-utilities':

```maxima
(%i1) load("mactex-utilities")$
(%i2) tex(a/b);
$$\frac{a}{b}$$
(%o2) false

(%i3) tex(matrix([1,2],[3,4]));
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
(%o3) false
```

> Barton

Therewith it should be no problem to render the equations with cdlatex from orgmode.

Comment: Thanks! Following the manual: http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_32.html, I now load this on session startup.